# What's the difference between 'savvy', 'shrewd', 'sagacious', 'perspicacious' and 'astute'?

Tags: difference

'Savvy', 'shrewd', 'sagacious', 'perspicacious' and 'astute' all mean sharp in judgement. But what's the nuance of them? What are some cases that one of them fit in well, but another is not so appropriate?

Comment: One way to research this would be to go to Google Books (or some other source) and search for these words to see how they're used in practice. What did you find when you researched their use?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan You mean things like [this](https://differencebee.com/shrewd-and-astute/#:~:text=SEARCH-,Difference%20Between%20Shrewd%20And%20Astute,-What%20is%20the)? They are defined using each other in this kind of difference blogs.

Comment: No, I mean for example going to books.google.com and searching "shrewd -intitle:shrewd". You can then restrict the results by date, document type, etc. if you want. Then you can look through the results and see how the word is actually used (at least in that particular corpus).

Comment: By the way, Merriam-Webster offers resources to distinguish among synonyms, too. For example, if you go to https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perspicacious and look under "Choose the Right Synonym for perspicacious", you'll find several of your terms described without referring to the others.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Oh, thanks for your details! I think this question is kinda too broad. I've voted to close it. Maybe I should ask several questions with more focus on certain situations.